# Can I add a placeholder to an input using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I just want to add placeholder="Search" to the input inside a div, it comes from a file  bootstrap file so I try to edit using css.
Here the div:

```
<div id="items-data-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>
   <input type="search" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="" aria-controls="items-data-table">
   </label>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not just use a placeholder?

Comment: you can even add it with JS after load: `document.querySelector("input[type=search]").placeholder="Search";`

Comment: You can add a placeholder from your input tag. And from CSS you can design the placeholder.

Comment: It's on a bootstrap file where this div and input is written, in devtools where i can see this.

Comment: What about googling "css placeholder" ?

Answer (score 0):

No, as @randomcoder66785 pointed out, you can use `::placeholder` to *style* the input. But any placeholder text must be defined via the html tag `placeholder`. You can even use JS to do that.

The simplest implementation would be this:

```
<div id="items-data-table_filter" class="dataTables_filter">
  <label>
   <input type="search"
          class="form-control input-sm"
          placeholder="Search" 
          aria-controls="items-data-table">
   </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

By using the ::placeholder selector,you can style and design the placeholder using your own codes.
Here's the W3Schools link:

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.asp

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Also w3schools is a poor resource

Comment: I think he wants to add the placeholder stuff using css. Not just styling it once set with HTML.